# Angular and ng-repeat directive

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have this piece of HTML code from a grid. I need to display different colors for each row deppending on the score value as if its from 0 to 4 it'll be green, from 5 to 7 yellow and from 8 to 10 red.

I plan to change the "tableColor" variable to the values: {success,warning,danger} depending on the score. I just dont know how to do that with the `ng-repeat` directive

```
<tbody>
     <tr class="{{tableColor}}" ng-repeat="firm in device.firmwares">
             <td>{{firm.fileName}}</td>
             <td>{{firm.extracted}}</td>
             <td>{{firm.Score}}</td>
             <td>{{firm.date}}</td>
      </tr>
</tbody>
```

If someone knows how to do it, I would appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```js
var app = angular.module("app",[]);

app.controller("ctrl" , function($scope){
  $scope.items = [{"name":"ali","score":2},{"name":"reza","score":4},{"name":"amir","score":5},{"name":"amir","score":7},{"name":"amir","score":5},{"name":"asd","score":10},{"name":"jim","score":8},{"name":"babak","score":6},{"name":"vfrt","score":8},{"name":"cdsa","score":7},{"name":"amir","score":10},{"name":"majid","score":3}];
  
  
  });
```

```css
.success{
  color:green;
  }

.warning{
   color:yellow;
  }

.danger{
  color:red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl" class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  
  <table>
     <tr ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class="{'success': item.score<= 4,'warning' :5<= item.score,'danger' : 8<=item.score }">
             <td>{{item.name}}</td>
             <td>{{item.score}}</td>
      </tr>
</table>
            
</div>
```

Comment: It work as a charm!, thank you very much man!!, saved my life!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<tbody>
     <tr ng-if="{{firm.Score <= 4}} " class="green" ng-repeat="firm in device.firmwares">
             <td>{{firm.fileName}}</td>
             <td>{{firm.extracted}}</td>
             <td>{{firm.Score}}</td>
             <td>{{firm.date}}</td>
      </tr>

     <tr ng-if="{{firm.Score >=5 & <=7 }} class="yellow" " ng-repeat="firm in device.firmwares">
             <td>{{firm.fileName}}</td>
             <td>{{firm.extracted}}</td>
             <td>{{firm.Score}}</td>
             <td>{{firm.date}}</td>
      </tr>

           <tr ng-if="{{firm.Score >=8 & <=10 }}" class="red" ng-repeat="firm in device.firmwares">
             <td>{{firm.fileName}}</td>
             <td>{{firm.extracted}}</td>
             <td>{{firm.Score}}</td>
             <td>{{firm.date}}</td>
      </tr>

</tbody>
```

**FOR CSS:**

```
.red { background-color: red; }
.yellow { background-color: yellow; }
.green{ background-color: green; }
```

Comment: promising solution, but instead of repeating the code 3 times, use the logic used in comment posted by Gabriel

Comment: it looks great, but when I try to run it, it doesn't, asi if there was an error on the code; I ended up using the ng-class as suggested in other comment, thank you very much for the help though!!

Answer (score 1):

Your code is perfect. You just need to change value of class "tableColor". Please do following code in your js file :

```
$scope.score = 4 // any dynamic value you can set. i think you already have.
if($scope.score <= 4)
{
   $scope.tableColor = "classGreen";
}
else if($scope.score >= 5 && $scope.score <= 7)
{
   $scope.tableColor = "classYellow";
}
else if($scope.score >= 8 && $scope.score <= 10)
{
   $scope.tableColor = "classRed";
}
```

and here in html this {{tableColor}} will affect that.

```
<tbody>
     <tr class="{{tableColor}}" ng-repeat="firm in device.firmwares">
             <td>{{firm.fileName}}</td>
             <td>{{firm.extracted}}</td>
             <td>{{firm.Score}}</td>
             <td>{{firm.date}}</td>
      </tr>
</tbody>
```