# Table on Angular, adding classes with ngClass and ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-class

I Have a table made from a Web Service JSON, on every row there is a button to mark the line to delete. When you click on the row button a JS alert show up the id of the row element, I need also add the 'danger' bootstrap class on the row. Now I can see the row element id when click the button and add the id to a a list for later send it to the web service.

This is my view:

```
<table class="table table-condensed">
                    <tr>   
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th><a href="" ng-click="sortField = 'ordre'; reverse = !reverse">Prioritat</a></th>
                        <th><a href="" ng-click="sortField = 'nomAtribut'; reverse = !reverse">Atribut</a></th>
                        <th><a href="" ng-click="sortField = 'nomAtribut'; reverse = !reverse">Tipus</a></th>
                        <th><a href="" ng-click="sortField = 'midaAtribut'; reverse = !reverse">Mida</a></th>
                        <th><a href="" ng-click="sortField = 'atributObligatori'; reverse = !reverse">Obligatori</a></th>
                        <th><a href="" ng-click="sortField = 'observacions'; reverse = !reverse">Observacions</a></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in atrb">
                        <td>
                            <a href="" ng-click="alert(value.idatributs_actiu)" ng-model="elimina"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="number" ng-model="value.ordre" value="value.ordre"   />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="value.valor" ng-model="value.nomAtribut" value="value.nomAtribut"   />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{value.valor}}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="value.valor" ng-model="value.midaAtribut" value="value.midaAtribut"   />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="value.atributObligatori" value="value.atributObligatori" ng-true-value="'Si'" ng-false-value="'No'" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="value.valor" ng-model="value.observacions" value="value.observacions"   />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

The controller:

```
$scope.alert = function (index) {
                    $window.alert('click a borrar id: ' + index); // Show JS alert with id
                    $scope.addAtributsExistentsEliminar(index); // Add id to array, for later send it to WS
                    $scope.elimina = true; 
                    $scope.class = 'danger';
                }
```

I've been trying to do it using [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) and following [other examples](http://code.ciphertrick.com/2014/12/06/highlight-a-selected-row-in-ng-repeat-using-ng-class/) and I'm getting nothing not even the JS alert and nothing shown on the JS console.

Edit:

I put the full controller code:

```
// Edita tipus d'actius
            assets.controller('EditaTipusCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams, $window) {

                    $scope.refresh = function () {
                        $http.get('http://10.0.203.73/WS/ws.php/tipusactius/getDetails/' + $routeParams.id).success(function (data) {
                            $scope.atrb = data;
                        });
                    };

                    $scope.alert = function (index, rowScope) {
                     //   rowScope.class = 'danger';
                        $window.alert('click a borrar id: ' + index); // Show JS alert with id
                        $scope.addAtributsExistentsEliminar(index); // Add id to array, for later send it to WS
                        $scope.elimina = true; 
                        rowScope.addClass = 'danger';
                    }

                    $scope.refresh();

                    // Construeix combo per definir tipus atributs (String, Date, Text)
                    $http.get('http://10.0.203.73/WS/ws.php/getCombo/1').success(function (data) {
                        $scope.options = data;
                    });

                    $scope.nousAtributs = [];
                    $scope.atributsExistentsEliminar = [];

                    $scope.addNewLine = function () {
                        var newRow = {
                            "nomAtribut": "",
                            "tipus": "",
                            "mida": '',
                            "prioritat": "",
                            "obligatori": "",
                            "observacions": "",
                            "nomTipusActiu": $routeParams.id // nom del tipus d'actiu
                        };
                        $scope.nousAtributs.push(newRow);
                    }

                    $scope.addAtributsExistentsEliminar = function (id) {
                        $scope.atributsExistentsEliminar.push(id);
                    }

                    $scope.showAtributsEliminar = function(){
                        angular.forEach($scope.atributsExistentsEliminar, $scope.show);
                    }

                    $scope.show = function (id) {
                        $http.get('http://10.0.203.73/WS/ws.php/tipusactius/edita/elimina/' + id + '.json').success(function (data) {
                            $scope.sts = data.status;
                            $window.alert($scope.sts);
                        });

                        if ($scope.sts.status == 'IN_USE') {
                            $window.alert('Aquest atribut no es pot eliminar perque és en ús');
                        }

                    }

                    $scope.saveChanges=function(){
                        angular.forEach($scope.atrb, $scope.sendChanges);
                        angular.forEach($scope.nousAtributs, $scope.saveNewAttributtes);
                        $('#myModal').modal('show');
                        $scope.refresh();
                    }

                    $scope.sendChanges=function(atribut){
                        $http.post('http://10.0.203.73/WS/ws.php/tipusactius/edita', atribut).success(function (data) {
                            $scope.atrb = data;
                        });
                    }

                    $scope.saveNewAttributtes=function(atribut){
                        $http.post('http://10.0.203.73/WS/ws.php/tipusactius/edita/nouatribut', atribut).success(function (data){
                            $scope.atrb = data;
                        });
                    }

                    $scope.removables = function () {

                    }

                });
```

Solved:

> Your current code tries to use the parent scope, which is why it's not
>   working as you expected. You can simply pass in the scope to the alert
>   function. So
>
> ```
> $scope.alert = function (index, rowScope) {
>   ...
>   rowScope.class = 'danger';
> }
> ```
>
> with your template as
>
> ```
> ...
>    <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in atrb" ng-class="class">
>       <td>    
>          <a href="" ng-click="alert(value.idatributs_actiu, this)"...
> ```
>
> Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/y0rtLhyj/

Comment: may be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36123999/angular-and-ng-repeat-directive/36124775#36124775

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code tries to use the parent scope, which is why it's not working as you expected. You can simply pass in the scope to the `alert` function. So

```
$scope.alert = function (index, rowScope) {
  ...
  rowScope.class = 'danger';
}
```

with your template as

```
...
   <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in atrb" ng-class="class">
      <td>    
         <a href="" ng-click="alert(value.idatributs_actiu, this)"...
```

---

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/y0rtLhyj/

---

That said, the right way would be to have something on your `value` object which indicates that it is deleted. Then use that to drive the `ng-class`. That way you don't have view properties (i.e. `class`) in your controller.

Comment: I did it but I'm getting this error on console: 'Cannot set property 'class' of undefined'

Comment: can you paste your HTML and script into my fiddle, fork it and post the link?

Comment: I changed: https://jsfiddle.net/hqu4th4z/ But don't know why on jsfiddle works but not on my server

Comment: I posted the full controller

Comment: in the fiddle you posted you are using `addClass` in the controller and `class` in the template.

Comment: I forgoten to add the ng-class on <tr> tag. Thank you.